# Clear Page Item in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am calling an IR with a link using a hidden page item to filter the IR records. The IR has a search region as well. Now when I click the link, the IR report opens with desired records.

Now as IR is already open and when I try to use the search region LOV to see other records it always shows me records with the previous page item hidden column even though I am changing the LOV.

how can I fix it?

IR query is as below:

```
(SELECT email_address, status, description FROM recipients
 WHERE recipient_group_id = NVL ( :P6_$RECIPIENT_GROUP_ID, recipient_group_id )
   AND recipient_id       = NVL ( :p8_recipient_id, recipient_id ))
```

The `:P6_$RECIPIENT_GROUP_ID` is coming from the previous page from where I am calling the IR using the link column.

The p8_recipient_id is the value coming from the search region of IR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is expected behaviour. The page item value for `:P6_$RECIPIENT_GROUP_ID` will be set until it is reset, either by setting the value to NULL or clearing the cache on page 6 (I'm assuming that is where this page item is defined).

If you want to clear the value of P6_$RECIPIENT_GROUP_ID then define a dynamic action on change of P8_RECIPIENT_ID to set P6_$RECIPIENT_GROUP_ID to NULL. Make sure the interactive report has attribute "items to submit" including both P6_$RECIPIENT_GROUP_ID and P8_RECIPIENT_ID.

Note: referencing a page item from another page is not a good practice. It may lead to unexpected results. A cleaner solution would be to define a P6_$RECIPIENT_GROUP_ID on page 8 and set that from the link to the IR.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable feedback. Request you explain a bit more about your last sentence in your previous reply, please? I am new to it so did not get quite what you are saying to modify.

Comment: In apex, page items belong to a page. It is possible to reference and use them on other pages but that isn't a good practice. If, for example you have a process that resets the session state for page 6 then the value of that P6_$RECIPIENT_GROUP_ID on page 8 will also be reset.
In your case, I'd define a P8_$RECIPIENT_GROUP_ID on page 8 and on page 6 build the link to the IR using P8_$RECIPIENT_GROUP_ID (since the link always points to page 8). That way you set an item on page 8 which belongs to page 8 itself. Does that make it clearer ?